# How to remove side and bottom border in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed collapsible accordion and in that I placed a table. 
I am unable to remove bottom boder of the `td` and side border of the table. I tried to make `no-tr.no-bottom-border td {border-bottom: none;` but it not working.

I tried to declare the class as outside and made tried border-bottom none but it didn't work.

```html
 Imported bootstrap js and css

 
   <style>

table {
    margin-left: 40px; 
    margin-right:auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
  }
 tr.no-bottom-border td {
 border-bottom: none;
 }
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 2px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
 #outside{
 border-style: none;
 
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container ">
 <div class="col-md-6 ">
 <div class="panel panel-default ">
 <div class="panel-heading " style="background-color: #b3daff; ">
 <h4 class="panel-title ">
 <a href="# "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "
 style="color: red "></span></a> <a data-toggle="collapse "
          data-parent="#accordion " href="#collapseTwo "> <span
          style="font-weight: 700; ">Educational Details</span> <span
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus " style="color: red ">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil " style="color: red ">&nbsp;</span>
         </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
       <div id="collapseTwo " class="panel-collapse collapse ">
       
    
      <table class="table table-bordered responsive ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor=" #b3daff ">Degree</th>
            <th bgcolor=" #b3daff ">Stream</th>
            <th bgcolor=" #b3daff ">Yr of Passing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>10th</th>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="outside " style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="font-weight: 400px; ">12th*</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row " >Bachelors*</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row ">Masters</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
            <th scope="row ">C1</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row ">C2</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row ">C3</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row ">C4</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
  <tr class="no-bottom-border ">
            <th >C5</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
             <td class="outside " style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; "><a href="# ">&nbsp;View</a>&nbsp;<a href="# ">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
     
     </div>
    </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!----Ends second column-------->
   </div>
   <!----Ends accordion column-------->

  </div>
  <!--  BS example ends here -->
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you mentioning the underlines below the View and Edit as border-bottoms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/gKPXJR

I have added

```
.table-bordered{   
  border: none;
}
```

and removed

```
tr.no-bottom-border td {
 border-bottom: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code snippet, I don't see any border-bottom in the table or any of the cells.

The underline below the links View, Edit is the default text-decoration style for  tag. Set it to none like below if you don't want it

```
#outside a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```